# Highcharts xAxis datetime from start

Tags: highcharts

As screenshots below, how can I set the first datetime from start?

**Code Demo Here:**

http://jsbin.com/wegunetayu/edit?js,output

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: null,
        series: chartData,
        tooltip: {
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                hour: '%A, %b %e, %l %p'
            },
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickLength: 0,
            labels: {
                align: 'left'
            },
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                hour: '%l %p'
            },
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: null
        }
    });
```

**Screenshots:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add these parameters to your `xAxis`:

```
xAxis: {
    startOnTick: true,
    minPadding: 0.01,
    ...
```

I updated your JsBin

*This solution work only there is enough space to show all months on the axis*